# Precisions on ODBC ports use

Tags: windows-7, networking, odbc

When creating a new ODBC source on windows 7, you have to provide the host and the port on which you want to connect :

[image: Some driver creation]

Since it is is managed by windows, I assume all ODBC driver work the same way in term of network consumption. 
I have two questions regarding the port requested by any ODBC driver:

- Will it be the only port used by the driver ?
- If I want to use this driver behind a firewall to connect to a remote Datasource, which rules shall I write ?

Comment: This is 100% based on your server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Every network communication involves one port on each end, which may be the same or different.  For instance, most Web communications involve a web browser which may be calling from any port at all ( from 1 to 65535), to a web server which typically listens on port 80 (http) or 443 (https).  Responses may simply take the reverse route -- or there may be two more ports involved.

Every ODBC driver works differently.  Every DBMS likewise.  Microsoft and/or Apache should provide documentation about firewall considerations, such as [this from my employer regarding our Multi-Tier Enterprise Edition drivers](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MTFirewallConfiguration).  The driver you're working with has [some docs here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-ODBC-driver/).